# MPlab-X hardware stack simulator not working

Tags: assembly, stack, simulator, mplab

I've written a very simple simple mpasm program to demonstrate how the hardware stack works on a midrange mpu (pic12F683).  The main loop calls a subroutine which calls another subroutine.  The subroutines do nothing ... they execute a nop and then return. I have program memory and hardware stack windows open.  Single stepping through the program gives the expected results ... program flow is as it should be ... and the first time through, the stack values get populated properly but the stack pointer remains 0 at all times.  When I try a debug build and simulate a second time, the stack values do not reinitialize to zero and I cannot find a way to manually initialize the stack window.

So my question is: is there a way to manually initialize the mplab simulator hardware stack window?  And how can I get the stack pointer to actually give an indication of TOS (top-of-stack)?

I'm guessing I'm not the first person to encounter this problem, so any insights/fixes would be appreciated.

Comment: Stack is typically uninitialized memory, until you put stuff in it. If your code actually depends on values on the stack not put there by your code then you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  My question is about the MPlab simulator.  The hardware stack in the PIC MCU only has 8 13-bit locations.  The only values to get stored there are return addresses put there by subroutine calls and processor interrupts.  The simulator shows the stack as being initialized to 0.  Although addresses seem to get placed in the stack correctly, the simulator never shows SP increment.  I'm trying to do a stack demo for a class I am teaching.  So, I'm looking to see if anyone has ever seen SP increment correctly so I can show a stack working correctly in MPlab-X.

Comment: Yeah the SP increment is indeed a problem.